# How to trigger multiple actions on conditional ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

For the following code snippet, how can i trigger both isEditable = !isEditable and edit(object); on span click. If I'l only pass a single action in the conditional ng-click it work fine, but how can I pass 2 or more action to be triggered?

The problematic attribute is the following one: ng-click="session.falg == true||isEditable = !isEditable;edit(object);"

What I would expected here is for the isEditable value to be toggeled and the edit(object) method to be called.

Note that the session.flag is available at the rootScope level, and edit(object) is available at the controller level in charge of this view.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="object in objectsArray">
    <div ng-show="!isEditable">
        <span ng-click="session.falg == true||isEditable = !isEditable;edit(object);">&nbsp;({{object.text}})</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="isEditable">
       <input type="text" ng-model="object.text" ng-blur="isEditable = !isEditable;updateObject(object);" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

---

The problem with having a single function to deal with this is that the 2 divs are part of a list (2 divs like the ones mentioned above will be displayed for each object available in my list ). So I'm not sure how to toggle the isEditable value(unique to each list element) with this approach.

An option will be to define an array  for this value but I believe it gets to cumbersome.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a fiddle.

Comment: The "OR" operator (||) cannot be used in an assignment statement like that. If you need to evaluate the session.falg before making the assignment, I'd put the whole thing into a function instead of the view.

Comment: Put the code in a controller and call the function: ng-click='doStuff()'.

Comment: The problem with having a single function to deal with this is that the 2 divs are part of a list (2 divs like the ones mentioned above will be displayed for each object available in my list ). So I'm not sure how to toggle the isEditable value(unique to each list element) with this approach.

An option will be to define an array for this value but I believe it gets to cumbersome.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can always add a new property to your objects in array, or create another object that maintains the state

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to avoid multiple actions written into HTML.

By following approach you lose:

- maintainability
- you can't debug
- code reuse
- code organization

Like @Gruff Bunny says, create one method in controller that you call on `ng-click`.

*Make your code simple.*